# jsRender - Is it possible to pass a template markup to another template?

Tags: jsrender

I want to use, for example, a `{{for}}` tag as follows and pass it an inline template:

```
{{for persons tmpl="{{>firstName}} {{>lastName}}" /}}
```

where

```
var person = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Resig"}, ...]
```

This is a simple case. I want to use this to pass a template markup to a custom tag without naming the passed template. I want the template to be defined inline.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is use nested templates.

```
{{for persons tmpl="#nameTemplate" /}}
```

Where `#nameTemplate` would be defined elsewhere.  The `persons` model would be passed in to that template, meaning you could define it like this:

```
<script id="nameTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <p>{{:firstName}}</p>
    <p>{{:lastName}}</p>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to use the template inline. I want to pass the template itself to another template but not its name. Fortunately this can be done  by using `{{include/}}` tag or programmatically `this.tagCtx.content` .